# PHPExcel write Excel and save to the server?

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

**The code I currently have:**

```
<?php

  /** PHPExcel */
  require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

  /** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
  require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

  // Create new PHPExcel object
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

  // Set properties
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                               ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                               ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                               ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                               ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                               ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                               ->setCategory("Test result file");

  $result = 'select * from table1';

  for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++) {

    $result1 = 'select * from table2 where table1_id = ' . $result[$i]['table1_id'];

    for ($j=0;$j<count($result1);$j++) {
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A' . $j, $result1[$j]['name']);
    }

    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Save Excel 2007 file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

    // Echo done
    echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";       
  }

?>
```

The above code executes and save n no of `.xlsx` files in the folder, but the problem I'm getting is biggest `count(result1)` in the `for` loop executing in all saved excel files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before going deep, one thing is clear

You haven't executed the query for $result, neither fetch it and on $result1 query you are using it which is not possible,

Same problem exist with $result1

You can use:

```
$result = mysql_query('select * from table1');
while($fetch_result=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $result2 = mysql("select * from table2 where table1_id = '".$fetch_result['table1_id']."'");

   while($fetch_result2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)
   {
    --your code--
```

But it is preferable to write JOIN instead of these two query

Answer (score 0):

You will want `mysql_num_rows` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
$q = 'select * from table1';
$res = mysql_query($q);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j=0;$j<$count;$j++) {
    #code here
}
```

you may also want to look at `mysql_fetch_assoc`